# How to update pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have installed pymongo-2.2-py2.7-linux-i686.egg and mongodb-2.0.5    on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 (Tikanga). I need to update pymongo and mongodb because with these version I can't use  Aggregation Framework http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/ , I updated mongodb to version mongodb-linux-i686-2.4.5 but still can't use aggregation framework , it looks that I need to update pymongo. How to update pymongo, I can't use pip , easy install, apt -get and similar, don't ask me why , I need to download correct pymongo version on my windows and transfer it via ftp to server , and install it manually , can someone tell me how to do it ? Is any other way to use aggregation framework on old versions of mongo and pymongo ...

With these version , when I tried to launch django wep app, that use aggregation function , I get this error :

Exception Value:

'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'aggregate' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.

Exception Location:

/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.2-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pymongo/collection.py in **call**, line 1197

Comment: You could install it from source: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/installation.html#installing-from-source Just download it from `github`, then upload it to your linux system

Comment: if I download pymongo from github, it will be correct version , I can't use git on my linux server, so can I downlaod that files from my local computer on windows, and transfer it to linux server  in /Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages and just run command  python setup.py install
 what will be with current installed pymongo , if I do it

Comment: Everything is ok, just you don't need to copy it into python lib directory, just in any other. It should install it into python lib automatically.

Comment: ok, thx,  i have little proble , don't know how to download localy on windows  git clone git://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver.git pymongo
 I tried with  GIT GUi for windows , but get error, can someone download it for me , and upload somewhere ...

Comment: Download it as a zip arch: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/archive/master.zip

Comment: thank you, I will try it now to install

Comment: i did it , but still can't use aggregation

Comment: now I get error Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.5.1_-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pymongo/helpers.py in _check_command_response, line 147

Comment: command SON([('aggregate', u'element'), ('pipeline', [{'$match': ...

Comment: when I add same aggregation query in mongo shell it works , but it won't works  with pymongo

Comment: Could you use aggregation into mongodb shell? ... oh, I see

Answer (score 0):

You may uninstall pymongo and then install it again. I couldn't find solution other than this.